# How to fix pants/legs "ripping in half" after rigging

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, weight-painting, rigify

i'm currently learning rigging using riggify so far everything is working great except one issue that I really don't know how to fix.

When I pull the leg up the pants seemingly break in half leaving a big hole between the leg area I think I may have to re-weight paint this area but everything i've attempted didn't not fix the issue.

I have attached a pic of the problem + my bone setup

[image: problem+bones]

Any even the slightest clue would help a lot. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix this is to parent the cloth to the armature. If it continues you can remove the cloth simulation as well.